# what's the tense of how about going?

Tags: tense

So I searched before and found thread are related for my question:

Reference: [ELL question on "How about going to the cinema tonight?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121743/how-about-going-to-the-cinema-tonight)

But it hasn't solved my question. ( by the way is it correct sentence? if I meant that problem not solved in the past but still in the present.)

Well,

> how about going to see her?

I can't find the tense and it pretty confused. because I know that,

```
wh- + an auxiliary verb + subject + main verb + ing => Present progressive.
```

I saw `going` for me it looks related to present progressive, but why the formulation is pretty different? where can I find extra details about this questions style?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Short answer - future tense.

> How about going out?

This is a question, and you are proposing to go out in the future - possibly the immediate future, possibly later, but either way you haven't begun "to go" out yet, so it can only be in the future. Also, the tense is *conditional* - it depends if the person you ask agrees.

I can see your confusion - many verbs ending with *-ing* are the present tense, for example:

> - I will dig a hole (future)
> - I am **digging** a hole (present)
> - I dug a hole (past)

Remember though that the present tense of many verbs also describes an *ongoing* or *continuous* action. Let's say that digging a hole will take 4 hours and you want to tell someone that you will busy with this all afternoon - you would say:

> I will be digging a hole all afternoon.

That shows that the *future* action of digging will be ongoing throughout the afternoon. If you simply said "*this afternoon I will dig a hole*" it does not carry the same information as to how long it will take.

Likewise there are other ways of saying you are *going* somewhere in the *future*:

> - I am going out tonight
> - I will be going to the party

Both of these are conditional on either it being a specific *time of day* or the correct time for a specific *event*.

Comment: How about + gerund does not contain a tense per se. It is a spoken form.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tense.  **going** is free of tense and can fit into statements about the future or the past.

> What shall we do tomorrow?
>   -- How about going to the zoo?

or

> It was so boring when we visited them last week. We couldn't think of anything fun to do.
>   -- How about going to the zoo?  Was it closed?

Here is a form that cannot be used with a past context but only with the future:

> What shall we do?
>   -- How about **we go** to the zoo?

or as an alternative to "how about":

> -- What say we go to the zoo?

Comment: Another set of examples:  I was going to see her.  I am going to see her.  I will be going to see her.  That's the exact phrase in question, in past, present, and future tense constructions.  The *-ing* form marks a continuous or progressive aspect, but it takes another verb in the construction to mark tense.

Comment: @Lambie: That's just you.  *How about closing the windows? Did you think to do that when it started to rain?*

Comment: @Lambie: There are plenty of contexts where the complement of **how about** would not be shortened to a simple noun phrase like "the windows".  A parent could be haranguing a teen, say, about all the things he or she had failed to do. *How about closing the windows when you got home.... how about taking the dog for a walk while we were away ... how about emptying the dishwasher before we got home ....* and so on.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I disagree with you on this issue. Let's leave it. I said it would be shortened and the objection would be in the **next utterance**, if this were a past event.That is my opinion. For me, the idea with the gerund is **always**something that is to come, not something that has been or was. I would teach it like that too, as future directed.

Comment: @Lambie: I think you're allowing the prospective sense of **how about** and the frequent association of **going**  with future contexts to  improperly influence your understanding here. There's no problem with the past tense:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seeing%20it%20caused%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Lambie: You wrote: "For me, the idea with the gerund is alwayssomething that is to come, not something that has been or was."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, it is. An idea about a near-future not using any tense. Going to the movies is a noun phrase. playing tennis,staying home, whatever. Going to a movie [noun phrase with the gerund going] is a good idea. You misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

*How about + gerund* is a s**poken form. Not a written one.**

**It is used to make suggestions in conversation(s) or refer to them.**

"How about going to a movie?"

Please note: going to a movie is a noun phrase. Like: staying home, playing tennis, listening to music.

It has no tense because the gerund is a noun.

"How about going to a movie?" is semantically equivalent to: 
"Why don't we go to a movie?".

As a form to make suggestions, **the meaning is about some future that takes place after the time it is spoken but there is no verb or tense in it per se.**

As is the case with other gerunds, it can take a possessive pronoun.

"Our leaving early is not a problem".

"How about our leaving early?" = Why don't we leave early?

Comment: Semantically equivalent doesn't make it the same. In your equivalent statement, the verb has been modified to "go". If you can modify it, it's a verb. Examples of gerunds, including yours, are spoken of posessively *as if they have already happened* - "**our** leaving early", or "do you ming **my** asking". You can't put a name to something that doesn't exist, likewise you can't make a noun out of a conditional future event that might not happen.

Comment: @Astralbee The point I was making is this: I can say to you: How about leaving now? And I could also say, **for the same idea**: Why don't we leave now? How about is tenseless: How about our leaving now. How about +gerund is a spoken form. And I do not understand your post (here)  and I believe you are misreading mine. I was specifically addressing: How about + gerund, with or without a possessive pronoun. These are spoken forms.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say someone says this:

> I'd like to go to the store on 3rd Street.

You can suggest a replacement to 3rd Street with *how about*:

> How about we go to the one on 4th Street instead.

Because we're really modifying the question, we can use a participle / participial phrase.

> How about going to 4th Street instead?

I believe *going* here is a verbal, not a normal verb per se - and is acting as a participle.  When verbs act as modifiers, often participles are used, and they don't have a tense.

I think the technical term for this is "adverbial participial phrase" or something like that.

Similar in concept to answering *Yes* or *No* to questions - these words are adverbs, definitely not complete sentences, but you don't get the entire picture without knowing the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

> *How about going to see her?*

There's not a great deal that can be said about this construction.

The idiom "how about" belongs to informal style where it's used to put forward a suggestion. The complement of "about" can be a noun phrase as in "How about another drink", a non-finite (untensed) gerund-participial clause as in your example, or a tensed declarative clause as in "How about we leave the job until next week?"